# SystemJS typescript woes?

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I just can't seem to understand modules and paths.  I'm writing a Chrome extension and trying to use typescript with angular2.  I kinda got it working once, but I wanted to restructure my directories.  It seems like every time I want to get a project setup or add files or pages I have this issue.  Is there anywhere to go to learn the rules for locating modules and javascript/typescript files?

What I want to do is have a `src` folder with my html, css (or less/sass), and typescript files and a `www` folder with my html, css and compiled js files.  I've setup my grunt tasks and they compile fine.  Since I'm using Angular 2 and in an extension I can't have inline scripts, I have two separate scripts for each page I'm creating, a `src/pages/index-page.ts` script that has the System setup and is loaded directly from `www/index.html` with `<script src="js/pages/index-page.js"></script>`:

```
declare var System : any;

System.config({
  packages: {
    appScripts: {                    
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});

System.import('js/pages/index-boot')
  .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

And the `src/pages/index-boot.ts` script that it should load

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {IndexApp} from './index-app';

bootstrap(IndexApp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
]);
```

Of course I get a network failure trying to load `/www/js/pages/index-boot`.  If I add the js, then it loads that file, but then I get errors finding `router` and `index-app`.

Why is `index-page` trying to load `index-boot` in the browser without the extension?  Do I need to organize my files differently?  Is there a site somewhere to explain all of this?  I don't get why I have to have three separate code files for one page (System config and import boot, boot, and app).

Answer (score 1):

> Why is index-page trying to load index-boot in the browser without the extension?

Because you have not asked it to do so. As far as I can see from your question there is no folder appScripts in your setup, and therefore defaultExtension: 'js' is simply ignored. To fix it an easy way use:

```
System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
```

See more here: [defaultJSExtensions](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#defaultjsextensions)

This will get you started while you are learning how to setup packages in systemjs ([packages](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages)), but note that this construct is deprecated.

As a starting point angular2 [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) is a good place. Note their usage of package called "app" and compare it to their folder structure - note 'app' folder there.

SystemJS you have to setup once per your application (index-page.js). Not for every page. Then you need some place to bootstrap your angular2 app (index-boot.ts), and then the rest of your application (app.ts and everything else) containing business logic

Comment: Is there a website somewhere to explain this?  Is having the package named 'app' important?  Does that correlate to a directory structure?  Relative to the html or to the page?  Can I use bundles like in the sample in their quickstart that way?  Can I have multiple packages?

Comment: Start with readme of the systemjs on github. No name 'app' is not important - its just a name of the folder with your compiled js files. Its relative to the 'System.baseURL' see readme for more info. You can have as many packages as you want. Usually every 'library' you use is a package, like rxjs, director, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

`defaultJSExtensions` will solve your extension issue.

```js
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true, // Will prepend .js to the module names
  paths: {
    '*': '/www/js/pages/*',  // If all your module are under /www/js/pages
    'angular2/*': '/path/to/angular2/*'
  },
  packages: {  // I don't see any appScripts package ref in your exemple, you can probably drop that one.
    appScripts: {                    
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

With this config, you can then simply do `System.import('index-boot')`

Comment: is there a way to tell angular2 and rx to use the provided bundles?

Comment: If you want to use the bundles, you'll have to load them using `script` tag and placed before `System.config`. You can also checkout [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) project (dev and prod build using System)

Comment: So the package name needs to refer to a directory on the server, and that makes it it's own module?  And that directory is specified by the property name in the packages object of the config object passed to `System.config`?  How does that correspond to what is loaded by `System.import`?  For instance if I have `js/appScripts` and do `System.import('js/appScripts/page.js')`, does the key have to be `'js/appScripts': {...}`?

Comment: You shoud read this: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages